# Creating a powercurve in an function block from table of values

Tags: simulink

I would like to create a 'Matlap function' block in Simulink for simulating an wind power plant with real data. Input should be wind speed, output power.

So far I struggle creating the function from a value table trying to use "polyfit" and "polyval". Is there another possibility?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use a [1-D Look-up table](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/simulink/slref/1dlookuptable.html)?

Comment: If the data exists in the base (or model) workspace, you can just parameterise the block with it. You can always load the data in one of the model callbacks if it's in a MAT file. See http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/simulink/ug/model-callbacks.html.

Comment: Tank you for your answer. I think this is the right way. Unfortunatley I don't know how to make it work correctly.
If I go to "File > Model Properties > Model Properties -> Callbacks -> PreLoadFcn" and write the name of my m-file which shall be executed when opening the model 
can this function be executed if it needs a variable from the workspace?

Comment: That's correct, your MATLAB script will get executed when the model is loaded and the variables will be created in the base workspace. Your can then use those variables to parameterise your model.